# Send Base64 as image on Mobile Share

Tags: javascript, android, base64, share

[Base64 data in IMG tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQgT2.png)

```
/*Allow native mobile share of QR */
function shareQROnMobile() {if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
      title: document.title,
      text:  document.title + ", " + window.location.href,
      url: jQuery("#qrcode-current img")[0].src,
  })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
}}
/*END native mobile share of QR */
```

This javascript code sends the base64 data string. Instead, I'd like this base64 converted to an image as is send to any application on the Android share menu.

How can I convert base64 string to an image and send that  to the share menu?